# Gnuplot does not work as Intended

Tags: 12.04, 32-bit

I have installed `Gnuplot 4.6.4` after downloading it from `sourceforge.net` and it does not have the wxt terminal. How can I remedy this issue? In addition to that the cursor position is not displayed in the `x11 window` the coordinates at the bottom left are frozen.

I think the issue is related to my inexperience in installing software in Ubuntu 12.04. I would appreciate it if you can assist me in the process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed from source? To have wxt you probably need the dev versions of wxWindows installed. In repositories you have 3.6.3 which works quite well...

Comment: I have installed from the source later found a guide explaining how to implement the wxt libraries and wxt terminal; I succeeded in doing so but the problem is it used to display the coordinates of the cursor.

Comment: It works for me in the stock 4.6.3 binaries installed with apt-get... don't know what could have happened.

Comment: Can you please add the solution in answer instead of "EDIT" in question. So that others can know your problem is solved.

Comment: @souravc Done as you told.

Answer (score 1):

Got the issue resolved the remedy was to add the option --with-readline=gnu while invoking the command ./configure. I don't know how it fixed the issue though. I followed a tutorial on the following URL: http://www.miscdebris.net/blog/2010/03/03/install-gnuplot-4-4-0-rc1-on-ubuntu-linux/